# Using reduce function to convert array to object

Tags: json, merge, jq

I want from the array (an output of another jq from a large json file) of this sort:

```json
[
  {
    "Action": {
      "name1": {
        "product": {
          "summary": "Summary Product"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "name2": {
        "gproduct": {
          "summary": "Summary Product"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "name3": {
        "product1": {
          "summary": "Summary Product1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "name3": {
        "product2": {
          "summary": "Summary Product2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

To obtain:

```json
{
  "Action": {
    "name1": {
      "product": {
        "summary": "Summary Product"
      }
    },
    "name2": {
      "gproduct": {
        "summary": "Summary Product"
      }
    },
    "name3": {
      "product1": {
        "summary": "Summary Product1"
      }
    },
    "name3": {
      "product2": {
        "summary": "Summary Product2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the jq: `reduce .[] as $o ({}; reduce ($o|keys)[] as $key (.; .[$key] += $o[$key] ))` gives:

```json
{
  "Action": {
    "name1": {
      "product": {
        "summary": "Summary Product"
      }
    },
    "name2": {
      "gproduct": {
        "summary": "Summary Product"
      }
    },
    "name3": {
      "product2": {
        "summary": "Summary Product2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the output file, name3 is listed only with the second product, I want all the products to be listed separately. If more than a product is available under a nameX, the result lists only the last product.

Comment: You cannot create the desired output because it contains the key `name3` twice for the object `Action`. Each key is only allowed once per object. Of course you can merge the values of `name3` as shown in the answer of @oguz ismail

Comment: Yes, I releazed that and actually fulfilled my task with the answer of @ogus ismail>
Thank you, both of you!
I can't find how to mark the question as answered, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multiplication operator for recursive merges.

```
reduce .[] as $obj ({}; . * $obj)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XdS5FSLmOI8)</sup>